# Is there an example of Google cloud translate for standalone Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-cloud-python, google-cloud-translate

I am trying to figure out how to use google cloud translate in my own Python3 environment.  I have completed the [codelabs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-translation-python3#0) that shows me how to do it in the cloud shell, but I want to run it from my own environment. I can install the google-cloud-translate library of course but I have no idea how to set up authentication, which in the tutorial uses a bunch of cloud shell commands that (AFAIK) I can't run from my Linux shell.

I did get a copy of the key.json file created in that process, in hopes there is a way to use that for my standalone system. But after quite a bit of searching I've not found any instructions for setting up authentication using that file or otherwise. There is a [guide](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup#linux_1) for setting up a Python dev environment, but it says nothing about authentication.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or worked example?

Comment: You can surely install gcloud in [linux](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb). Or alternatively you can do everything they do in this lab [related to enabling things] in google cloud console (Web UI) instead. If stuck, let us know which gcloud command you struggle with.

Comment: OK got gcloud SDK installed.  Two questions. (1) When I gave my phone number for login, it logged me into a different google id than the one I completed the lab on, and for which I have the $300 free trial. How to get to that account? (2) So all I need to do is run the same steps in the lab using this gcloud instead?

Comment: The gcloud in cloud shell isn't any different from the one you now have on your computer, so yes, just use it the same way. As for the account - only you would know. When you register, I believe you always provide your email address, and thus you should have registration email in your inbox.

Comment: OK got it configured with the right account. Now to the step in the lab where is starts installing python packages. Another doc https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup says to install python packages using venv, but the lab doesn't do that. Should I do it? If so the first step is "cd your-project". Is that the gcloud project name? I have no dir by that name.

Comment: This is very much python related. If you want to work in the venv (good practice) - do so, otherwise, work with the system-wide python. As for where to cd or what to do, I think the best thing is to understand why you are doing certain things, because there is no one recipe to go about creating a project.

Comment: Any updates on this, if so, could you provide it as an answer? If not, could you update me on the issues you're having now to keep troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

You can first install [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb), like someone on the comments said.

After that, to authenticate I would set up the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable with the path to your service account key

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/my/service-account-key.json"
```

You can add it to your `.bashrc` if you don't want to run it each time you log in